# Hide navigation from non-authenticated users in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system, navigation

Is there an easy way in Drupal 6 to turn off certain navigation items from non-authenticated users?  I'm having a hard time finding out how searching Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you: [node_privacy_byrole](http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole)

[Thread](http://drupal.org/node/116903) on drupal forums.